# how to display all lines from one that match regex in linux

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk, grep

I want to display all lines from one which match regular expression

if I have a file

```
foo
bar123
baz12435
lorem
ipsum
dolor
sit
amet
```

this `display-from baz[0-9]* < file` sould return (It doesn't matter if it display matched line or not)

```
lorem
ipsum
dolor
sit
amet
```

How can I do this in Linux (with sed, awk or grep)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sed -e '/baz[0-9]*/,$b' -e 'd' file
```

This will delete all lines from the input except the ones from the first line that matches the regex (/baz[0-9]*/) to the end of the file ($).

Answer (score 7):

Just use grep:

```
$ grep -E 'baz[0-9]*' file -A9999
```

Here, the '[-A](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Context-Line-Control)' option tells grep how many lines to display after the match. It's a bit clunky, but if there's an upper bound on the length of your input files, it might work OK.

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer prints the line which includes the pattern. If you want to exclude that line:

```
sed  '1,/baz[0-9]*/d' file
```

A simpler version of the accepted answer:

```
sed  -ne '/baz[0-9]*/,$p' file
```

Some versions of `sed` don't need the `-e` except in certain circumstances (but accept it anyway) and some do. These examples illustrate both types.

Answer (score 1):

use awk

```
awk '/baz/{f=1;next}f' file
```

Answer (score -1):

I use grep to search a keyword in a file. I use the following:

```
Syntax => grep pattern filename
examlpe
grep amet /path_to_file
```

Answer (score -1):

```
ruby -ne 'print unless 1 .. /baz[0-9]/' file
```